# How do I interpret an incorrect result?

Tags: svm, libsvm

I have been using libsvm.  It produces some good results (95% on positives, 94% on negatives).  When I examine the ones that it gets incorrect, however, I am confused about *why* it got them wrong.  How do I determine what it is doing wrong?  (More importantly, how do I explain it to my boss?).  Some of the testing inputs it gets wrong are very close (visually) to some of the testing inputs it gets right.

About my problem:  I am looking at images, 32x32 pixels, 8-bit greyscale.  I am evaluating different feature detectors and using them as a dense representation (i.e. at every pixel) of the image.  Hence, my feature length is often 1024; some of the feature detectors have multiple outputs, sometimes I do not use every pixel but every 3rd or 5th, etc..  It is a binary classification task, looking for figures in the image; for example, I am trying to find a square, with various letters for negatives.  The SVM does well.  But sometimes, it will classify a T as a square, and I don't know why.  If I'm using probabilities, then sometimes the probability is quite high.  What do I do to get an insight into what it is doing and why?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Can you provide an example and code?